# Virtual VMWARE Ubuntu - OpenVpn connects manually but AUTH-FAIL at boot

Tags: virtualbox, vmware, openvpn

This was working perfectly in VirtualBox.  We moved it to VMware and our OpenVpn connection stopped automatically connecting.  We check the sys log, and see the service is starting and then we get an auth failed message.

This is what i see in SysLog

```
systemd[1]: Started OpenVPN service.
.... middle stuff
AUTH: Received control message: AUTH_FAILED
```

and then the service seems to be offline and never retries.  HOWEVER - if i type the following :

```
service openvpn restart
```

Then it connects without errors and works just fine.  Something about switching from VirtualBox to VMware created this problem.  Might anyone have a clue what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seem to stem from the VirtualBox Guest Addition tools.

When I issued the command :

```
systemctl start openvpn@server.service
```

That repaired the openvpn, but then i realized i had the Vbox guest additions running and being i am now using VMware, I removed them to get rid of the SysLog errors.

```
/opt/[VboxAddonsFolder]/uninstall.sh
```

And that messed with the systemctl again, and I had the problem back.  I once again issued the command.

```
systemctl start openvpn@server.service
```

And i was back in business. This leads me to believe that the VirtualBox additions messed with the systemctl.  I have done a few reboots and everything comes up the way it should, so, i believe all is good.